# Regex to select path from url to use it in preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, path

1. How to select with regex in php everything in `http(s)://domain.tdl/path` url after `http(s)://domain.tdl` to get `/path` to use it in `preg_replace()` as a search pattern.
2. Another question: How to fill `preg_replace()` parametrs with regex in one string in order to get from original full url `http(s)://domain.tdl/path` only `http(s)://domain.tdl`.

I cannot change code of php script, and I send `preg_replace()` parameters from a web form. I can only pass `@pattern` and `@replacement` parameters of preg_replace() in that web form.

P.S. Urls and domains always differ.

Thanks!

Comment: People expect to see what you tried (your code), in a well formatted question. Help them help you. Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: I am beginner in php, so I do not know what to try. That's why I asked the question here.
I've read "overflow tour" and "how to ask".

Comment: No, I need regex not `parse_url()`.
I need to pass `preg_replace() ` parameters through a form on a website. I cannot change code.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg maybe any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you just want to get the domain with the protocol, and also the path on the end. If so, try this:

```
$url    = 'https://domain.tdl/path';
$urlArr = parse_url($url);
var_dump("$urlArr[scheme]://$urlArr[host]"); // Returns http://domain.tdl
var_dump($urlArr['path']); // Returns /path
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/1042710)

This uses PHP's [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to, funnily enough, parse the url.

---

Or, if you really need to use regex, try this:

```
$url = 'https://domain.tdl/path';
preg_match('/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[a-z]+\.[a-z]+)(\/.*)/i', $url, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]); // Returns http://domain.tdl
var_dump($matches[2]); // Returns /path
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/VsuL0n/1), [eval.in demo](https://eval.in/1042717)

Comment: strange indeed :) a php function whose name is representative of the capability offered !

Comment: No, I need regex not parse_url(). I need to pass preg_replace() parameters through a form on a website. I cannot change code.

Comment: Ok @Jesty , I've updated my answer.

Comment: @David As I said I cannot change code, and I send `preg_replace()` parameters from web form. I can only pass `@pattern` and `@replacement` parameters of `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @David thanks! In web form I used your pattern `(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[a-z]+\.[a-z]+)(\/.*)` to pass as `@pattern` parameter, and `$1` value to pass as `@replacement` parameter. And that did the trick!